# How do events influence a transaction's gas?

Tags: gas, events, gas-price

Since events are stored in the transaction receipts trie they should influence the gas a transaction costs since storage costs, right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The increase it by `375 + 375 * numberOfIndexedParameters + numberOfUnindexedBits`.

For example:

```
event Event(uint16 indexed a, uint32 indexed b, uint64 c, uint128 d);
emit Event(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

The additional cost is `375 + 375 * 2 + 64 + 128`.

Comment: Source for this?

Comment: @Jaime: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethdev/comments/78ugki/do_indexed_parameters_in_events_cost_more_gas/